# How to increase first column's width on SQLPlus?

Tags: sqlplus

I want to try increase the width of my first column on a returned result, but it is being cut off by the second column, I have tried linesize but this does not seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

say the column name is col1.

Before executing any select add this line to the command script, test it on the sqlplus command line ---  I'm assuming col1 is VARCHAR2.

```
-- this makes col1 15 characters wide
COL col1 format a15
```